# Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: java, azure

Estoy desarrollando una Azure Function en Java de tipo `@TimerTrigger`. Cuando intento ejecutar este Function, el emulador del Azure me lanza este error:

> The listener for function 'ABC123' was unable to start.

> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

o en ingles:

> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Lo mas raro es que con `@HttpTrigger` no me sale este error. Saben si necesito hacer alguna configuración adicional en mi maquina o en el emulador de Azure?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta agregando el código que genera el error?

Comment: Fue solucionado, solo bastó instalar e iniciar el Azure Emulator. Gracias.